# Binary file image doesnt translate into a clear image upon implementation of python code

Tags: python, image, matlab, numpy, matplotlib

I implemented a python code that reads a binary image file to display the image. The image is unclear and nothing like that I obtained while implementing a similar code on MATLAB. I have attached both the images here: ([img obtained using python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdov0.png); [Original img using matlab code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEzxy.jpg)). Here is the python code for the same:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
from scipy import misc

A = np.fromfile('/home/shruthi/Desktop/1485999630.bin', dtype='int16', sep="")

A = A.reshape([1216, 1216])
imgplot = plt.imshow(A)
imgplot.set_cmap('gray')
plt.show()
```

I have also attached the MATLAB code for reference:

```
file= fid = fopen('1486445720.bin');
HDR = reshape(fread(fid,1216*1216,'uint16'),1216,1216);
fclose(fid);
HRGB = demosaic(uint32(HDR'),'rggb');                % Valid for Matlab 2016 and make sense only if HDR is double
RGB = tonemap(double(HRGB), 'AdjustLightness', [0.1 1],'AdjustSaturation', 8);
```

Comment: How did you generate the 1485999630.bin file?

Comment: The .bin file is the output data received from skycameras. This data is directly sent into a server, which I have access to. I wish to translate the same into a clear image.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you'd probably want to try is using `uint16` instead of `int16`.

Your working matlab code suggests that your raw data are encoded in a [Bayer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter), meaning that the colour channels are interleaved in some way. The matlab `demosaic` function separates the channels and returns a more useful representation.

You need to do the same in your python code. I haven't found an "official" numpy function for that but you can try and use/adapt [this](https://github.com/adrn/pyraw/blob/master/pyraw/rawimage.py).